# Interaction Design Foundation - Interested in Hearing Experiences

Tags: education

I found what looks like an interesting course: The Psychology of Interaction Design being given by the Interaction Design Foundation. (https://www.interaction-design.org/courses/psychology_of_interaction_design-_the_ultimate_guide.html)

Has anyone used them before, or heard anything about them?

Comment: Answers to this would be purely opinion based, and would quickly lose relevance over time. I've read several items put out by IDF, and have nothing against what they produced, but the type of answers to this type of question are not suited well for this type of format.

Comment: fair enough. Would this be better suited to the chat section? Never used it but perhaps that would be a better fit?

Comment: Yes, this question would be a better fit for the chatroom.